# IIS Url Rewrite - Subdomain to folder issue results 404

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, dns

I want anySubdomain.mydomain.com to behave as mydomain.com/anySubdomain. My configs so far:

1. I entered a wildcard CNAME record (*.mydomain.com CNAME mydomain.com) in DNS records of mydomain.com. I am pretty sure this step is ok.
2. I created an inbound rule in URL Rewrite module of web site in IIS as:

   ```
   <rewrite>    
   <rules>    
       <rule name="Subdomain to Folder" stopProcessing="true">    
           <match url="(.*)" />    
           <conditions>    
               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="[http://]*(.*).mydomain.com" />    
           </conditions>    
           <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />    
       </rule>    
   </rules>
   ```
3. I created a folder under root folder as anySubdomain and put an index.html into it. I have checked that mydomain.com/anySubdomain gets the page that I want.

I receive a 404 page when I call anySubdomain.mydomain.com. I know this is a common issue but I could not solve this problem, where is my mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer, let me share it.
The missing step was to add following IIS binding to catch all "has not yet assigned hostnames requests":

```
IP Address: IP of web server    
Port: 80    
Host: (Leave Blank)
```